# Are intentional value overflows safe?

Tags: c, windows, integer-overflow

This question is probably stupid or paranoidal, but anyway :-). Given following code:

```
DWORD hiRes;

// will overflow about once in an hour
hiRes = GetTickCount() * 1193L;
```

If it known that `hiRes` overflows periodically and such situations are handled properly, is there anything wrong with this code?

**UPDATE:** 
Result is quite surprising for me, since the answer depends on the type of `hiRes` (signed or unsigned), which is defined by C Standard ([see for example](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html)).

Comment: There are no such things as stupid questions, only stupid answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overflowing an `unsigned int` is safe. Overflowing a signed one isn't (undefined behavior).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) says:

> A DWORD is a 32-bit **unsigned** integer (range: 0 through 4294967295
>   decimal). This type is declared as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned long DWORD
> ```

So it should be safe.

Comment: DWORD is "typedef unsigned long DWORD;" in Windows. In what way signed owerflows are not safe? That's the difference with unsigned?

Comment: They're unsafe in that the C standard says they're undefined behaviour. On a Windows platform though I don't think you're going to see anything unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned integers are safe, signed are not. But I've never come accross a platform that doesn't do the obvious twos complement thing. I do wish the standards people had bitten the bullet and just made it mandatory.

Comment: Any good compiler will optimize assuming your code does not invoke signed overflow. This means code that relies on predictable behavior from signed overflow is broken.

Comment: See also [exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about)  :-)