# how to get size of file bigger than LONG_MAX in c?

Tags: c, filesize

how do you get the size of a file bigger than LONG_MAX in C?

I know you can use fopen+SEEK_END+ftell as long as your filesize don't exceed LONG_MAX, but what if it does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[0], "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%ld\n", fsize);
}
```

in C++ i would use `std::filesystem::file_size()` returning `std::uintmax_t`

Comment: Can such a file exist?

Comment: @user207421 yes, welcome to MSVC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279540/1067003 (MSVC has a non-portable _ftelli64() function returning 64bit tho)

Comment: Use `GetFileSizeEx()` or `_filelengthi64()` on Windows, `fstat()` on Unixy systems.

Comment: A single file of more than 18000000TB ?

Comment: @ulix worried about a single file of more than 4GB (long is only guaranteed to be >=32bit, and in the name of backwards-compatibility, MSVC takes advantage of this and defines long as 32bits. then MSVC makes a non-portable _ftelli64() function to work around the 4gb issue)

Comment: @hanshenrik MSVC does not make any functions. It is part of win32 library

Answer (score 2):

The comment suggests windows.

You have plenty of functions in Windows:

- `_fstat, _fstat32, _fstat64, _fstati64, _fstat32i64, _fstat64i32`
- `GetFileSizeEx`
- `ftell, _ftelli64`

Unfortunately you need to use `#if`s to compile your programs for windows and Linux.

Comment: `fstat??( fileno( filePtr, &statBuf ) )` works as long as you can stomach/silence MSVC's attempts to make you write non-portable code in its efforts to perpetuate vendor lock-in - **and** you read the MS documentation to make sure you get a 64-bit compatible `stat()` call (yeah, that maintains vendor lock-in but it's trivial to `ifdef` around).  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside the file size issue, using `ftell` to seek to the end of a file isn't a good way to do so as it incurs extra I/O (at least on a traditional disk drive, not sure about SSD) to do so.

A file's size is included as part of its directory entry, so it's best to get it directly from there.  On UNIX-like systems, you would use the `stat` call, while on Windows you could call `_stat` (32-bit file size) or `_stat64` (64-bit file size).  These also don't require that the file be opened.

These corresponding functions and types are close enough that you can use `#if` directives to set up a common type you can use in either case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// defined by MSVC
#ifdef _MSC_VER

typedef struct _stat64 stat_struct;
#define stat_func(name, buf) _stat64(name, buf)

#else

#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct stat stat_struct;
#define stat_func(name, buf) stat(name, buf)

#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    stat_struct stat;
    stat_func(argv[1], &stat);
    printf("%lld\n", stat.st_size);
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer `#if _WIN32` over `#ifdef _MSC_VER` - I believe `_MSC_VER` is MSVC-specific, but `_WIN32` *will* positively identify Windows.  `_WIN32` works for a code base that I support that gets built on Windows under MSVC and GCC, and under GCC on Linux.