# Why does the C++ standard algorithm "count" return a difference_type instead of size_t?

Tags: c++, std

Why is the return type of [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) the `difference_type` of the iterators (often a `ptrdiff_t`).

Since count can never be negative, isn't `size_t` *technically* the right choice? And what if the count exceeds the range of `ptrdiff_t` since the theoretical possible size of an array can be `size_t`?

---

**EDIT:** So far there is no suitable answer as to why the function returns `ptrdiff_t`. Some explanation gathered from the answers below is that the return type is `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` which is generic and can be anything. Up until that point it makes sense. There are cases where the count may exceed `size_t`. However, it still does not make sense why the return type is `typedef ptrdiff_t iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` for the standard iterators instead of `typedef size_t iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type`.

Comment: It's `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` according to my documentation.

Comment: @awoodland: `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` is a typedef for `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: That depends on what type `InputIterator` is -- it's a template parameter.

Comment: It doesn't have to be though. Out of interest what does `Allocator::max_size()` return for the allocator used with your container? I suspect it is a non-issue for everything except *possibly* `char`, which may have a different specialisation.

Comment: @awoodland: That doesn't sound the reasoning of an engineer writing the STL functions :P. It is a non-issue similar to the non-issue of using `int` for iterating through a `vector` container... until you have a container big enough to go past the range of `int`.

Comment: @Samaursa - the only container that can possibly do that is `char`. My bet is that the `iterator_traits::difference_type` already existed when this was added (it was added after another older variant of `count`) and they didn't want to force every specialisation of `iterator_traits` to have to be updated. I can't find the precise point at which it was added (I'm looking though), but doing this without adding another `typedef` kept the scope of the change very local.

Comment: @awoodland - Who says that the iterators have to belong to a container? The sequence could be on disk or part of some network traffic. A user defined iterator could have a difference_type much large than size_t.

Comment: @awoodland: you're assuming an architecture with a "simple" addressing scheme.  Ever heard of [exotic architectures the C++ standard committee cares about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about)?

Comment: @BoPersson that's exactly it then - the specialisation of `iterator_traits` gives you freedom still to have types which aren't just `std::size_type`.

Comment: @awoodland: That is fine, but why have it incorrect in the first place? In this case `ptrdiff_t` has no advantage over `size_t`, only a disadvantage.

Comment: @Samaursa - it's not ptrdiff_t, it's iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type

Comment: @Samaursa Using `std::size_t` directly has a serious disadvantage: the integral type can't change based on the type of iterator.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Ok, that part makes sense, but the part where `difference_type` is a typedef of `ptrdiff_t` does not. Sure, I can change that for my own custom iterators, but why choose `ptrdiff_t` for the standard iterators?

Comment: @Samaursa, I presume the standards committee wanted `difference_type` to be able to specify the difference between any two iterators, even if the difference were negative.

Answer (score 21):

The `std::count()` algorithm relies on the iterator type to define an integral type large enough to represent any size of a range.  Possible implementation of containers include files and network streams, etc.  There is no guarantee that the entire range fits into the process' address space at once, so `std::size_t` might be too small.

The only integral type offered by the standard `std::iterator_traits<>` is `std::iterator_traits<>::difference_type`, which is suitable for representing "distances" between two iterators.  For iterators implemented as (wrappers of) pointers, this type is `std::ptrdiff_t`.  There is no `size_type` or the like from iterator traits, so there is no other choice.

Answer (score 12):

`size_t` is not technically the correct choice, since it might not be big enough. Iterators are permitted to iterate over "something" that is larger than any object in memory -- for example a file on disk. When they do so, the iterator can define a type larger than `size_t` as its `difference_type`, if one is available.

`difference_type` needs to be signed because in contexts other than `std::count` it represents offsets between iterators *in both directions*. For random access iterators, `it + difference` is a perfectly sensible operation even when `difference` is negative.

`iterator_traits` doesn't offer an unsigned type. Maybe it should, but given that it doesn't `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` is the best type available.

The issue of whether iterators should offer an unsigned type probably relates to a massive conflict of coding styles, whether unsigned types should be used for counts at all. I don't propose to reproduce that argument here, you can look it up. `ptrdiff_t` does have a weakness that on some systems it cannot represent all valid pointer differences, and hence also cannot represent all expected results of `std::count`.

As far as I can tell, even in C++03 the standard actually forbade this, maybe by accident. 5.7/6 talks about subtraction possibly overflowing `ptrdiff_t`, just like C does. But table 32 (allocator requirements) says that `X::difference_type` can represent the difference between any two pointers, and `std::allocator` is guaranteed to use `ptrdiff_t` as its `difference_type` (20.1.5/4). C++11 is similar. So one part of the standard thinks that pointer subtraction can overflow `ptrdiff_t`, and another part of the standard says it can't.

`std::count` presumably was designed under the same (possibly defective) assumption as the allocator requirements, that `ptrdiff_t` is big enough to express the size of any object and (in general) an iterator's `difference_type` can express the count of iterands between any two iterators.

Comment: Does whatever the iterators iterate over have to define `size()`? Size returns `size_t`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: that's not correct. If `C` is a container, then `C::size()` returns `C::size_type`. There is no requirement that the `size_type` of a container must be `size_t`. It can be any unsigned type, and it is permitted to be larger than `size_t`. The containers and allocators in the standard use `size_t`, but not all containers or allocators are standard ones.

Comment: Right, `size_type`. The point is, `size_type` is unsigned and it doesn't make sense for `count` to return a signed value.

Comment: Anyway the answer is no. You can have iterators over things other than collections, although the common example is that a pointer is an iterator over an array. Which doesn't define `size()`, but of course still fits in `size_t` ;-) If you're suggesting that `iterator_traits` should define an unsigned type, then you'd have to argue your case with the standards committee, but two answers here discuss the unavoidable fact that it doesn't define one.

Comment: What does the "size of any object" or "the difference between any two pointers" have to do with iterators though? If we're going to overflow `std::size_t`, there's no reason to think we can't overflow `std::ptrdiff_t` too, so we've just traded well-defined behavior for undefined behavior???

Answer (score 5):

The return type is `typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` which in this particular case happens to be `ptrdiff_t`.

Presumably `difference_type` was selected because the maximum number of matching elements in the range would be the iterator difference `last - first`.

Comment: Problem is, that difference is only negative if the range is invalid, and using such an invalid range in a standard algorithm is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, `difference_type` is obviously able to contain the complete count under all circumstances, but `ptrdiff_t` is not - consider the case of an iterator over a file object when the pointer size is only 32 bits.

Comment: @Tomalak, because the count must be less than or equal to the size of the range. This assumes that `difference_type` is guaranteed to hold the size of the range, which I haven't verified, but I'd be extremely surprised if it was not.

Comment: @Mark: n3290's table 28 says that it's "a type that can represent the
difference between any two pointers in the allocation model". I suppose that's the same thing. :)

Comment: @MarkRansom : AFAIK, `difference_type` is *not* guaranteed to hold the size of the range, because of the standard's allowance for `__far` pointers.

Comment: @ildjarn, the existence of __far pointers doesn't automatically rule out a guarantee because the difference_type is specialized on the type of iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Originally `std::count` was:

```
template <class InputIterator, class EqualityComparable, class Size>
void count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
           const EqualityComparable& value,
           Size& n);
```

In that function `Size` is a template parameter. It can be whatever you like, and it's your responsibility to make sure it's correct. It could be the longest type on your platform.

My suspicion is that when the newer form:

```
template <class InputIterator, class EqualityComparable>
iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
      const EqualityComparable& value);
```

was added `iterator_traits` was already in existence, so re-using the existing type had the advantage that it kept the changes to the standard small and localised, compared to adding another `typedef` in `iterator_traits`.

Doing it this way, using `iterator_traits` as opposed to simply using `std::size_type` means that every possible iterator gets the option to specify exactly what type should be returned by `std::count`. This includes custom iterators which read from a network, or disk, which can use something much larger than either `ptrdiff_t` or `size_type` and friends. (It *could* be some kind of "BigInt" if needed). It also means that the user isn't responsible for deducing the appropriate type to use though, which can be tricky, precisely because of the custom iterator possibility.

Answer (score -1):

Even though a count can't be negative, the return type is specified as `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` and the difference between two iterators *can* be negative.

Comment: Which only begs the question -- why is the return type `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` rather than `std::size_t`?

Comment: Sure, I understand the difference can be negative... but that has nothing to with `count`ing... (EDIT: didn't see ildjam's post)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, as `std::count` doesn't return *difference between two iterators*.

Comment: @ildjarn, `difference_type` is obviously able to contain the complete count under all circumstances, but `size_t` is not - consider the case of an iterator over a file object when the pointer size is only 32 bits.

Comment: @Nawaz: there is no other integral type that can be deduced from the iterator type except for `std::iterator_traits<>::difference_type`.

Answer (score -1):

If the iterator was an array, it would imply the result is within the range of the array.

For this specific algorithm I can't think of a reason that is interesting.  For someone using this as a component it may be interesting, though.

The page does say that it would do something *equivalent*.  So for the case of an array it may do something like a direct pointer difference.  This would be a pretty fast specialization if it were applicable.

Answer (score -1):

`difference_type` usually denotes the type suitable to denote a distance in an array or similar. The following wording is from the allocator requirements, but whenever the standard talks about `difference_type` it means the same concept:

> a type that can represent the difference between any two pointers in
>   the allocation model

The natural type for this is ptrdiff_t.

For the `size_type` it says:

> a type that can represent the size of the largest object in the
>   allocation model.

The natural type here is size_t.

Now for the count of any elements in a range (or an array) does need at least the type suitable to specify the difference `last-first`. It seems most natural to chose that one.

Comment: No, it’s not natural at all. `size_t` can, by definition, *also* specify the difference `last-first`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Of course size_t can hold the value (when it is positive) but when last and first are pointers, the type is defined to be the same as std::ptrdiff_t is a typedef of.