# Why do std::count(_if) return iterator::difference_type instead of size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm, library-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the C++ standard algorithm “count” return a ptrdiff_t instead of size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505083/why-does-the-c-standard-algorithm-count-return-a-ptrdiff-t-instead-of-size-t)

There is algorithm `std::count`/`std::count_if` in standard C++.

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value);

template<class InputIterator, class Predicate>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

> Effects: Returns the number of iterators i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding
>   conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false.

`difference_type` is `iterator's difference_type`, which can be negative, but `count` can return only value >= 0. Why `difference_type` and not `size_t` for example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In theory you may have a tremendous sequence whose number of elements can only be represented with 128 bits. Assuming the implementation supports a corresponding integer type, it is quite likely that `size_t` use a 64 bit type. However, the iterator for this huge sequence could use a 128 bit integer. Note, that the sequence isn't necessary represented in the memory of any individual computer. It may be split across multiple huge databases.

You might also have a relatively small computer supporting only a 32 bit type with reasonable performance. For full standard conformance it might have to support a 64 bit type but it can be desirable to rather support faster computations using a representation natively supported by the platform. That is, `size_t` may not be the optimal choice. When creating iterators you generally know what size needs to be supported.

Comment: @DietmarKuehl  But why is `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` a better choice? It is an 8-byte-signed integer in most cases, which already breaks down the argument that `size_t` (8-byte-unsigned integer) may not be large enough!

Comment: @GrimFandango: How does the choices made for other iterators affect my choice of `TremendousIterator::difference_type`? The point is that using `std::size_t` would prevent special cases to use special choices while using the nested type allows to make suitable choices.