# Why does std::count return a signed integer?

Tags: c++, types, containers, std

I was really surprised to see that `std::count` returned a `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type`, which in turns refers to a `long int` on my platform.

Why is that? A negative count elements within a container doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: The difference will be only negative if the range is invalid, and this yields an undefined behavior during the algorithm.

Comment: This discussion may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505083/why-does-the-c-standard-algorithm-count-return-a-ptrdiff-t-instead-of-size-t?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic, I am confused. Is it undefined behavior or not? I mean, either the iterators boundaries are checked and it returns a negative value on error, or it is undefined behavior and then what it returns is undefined.

Comment: Please refer to Joachim's answer - `std::count` just returns the distance between two iterators which can be negative of course once you chose an invalid range. Undefined behavior is in this case when you count from let's say n+1 to n. How will this work? This depends on the types and the iterators used.

Comment: "A negative count elements within a container doesn’t make any sense." - you seem here to be on the verge of suggesting that unsigned types "should" be used wherever a negative value is impossible. There are a great many experienced C++ (and C) programmers who would strongly disagree with that suggestion. You also seem to restrict the discussion to containers. Iterators aren't only for iterating containers, they can also iterate other things, although no matter what they're iterating it's true that a negative count makes no sense.

Comment: @SteveJessop You have my full attention now :) Would you have anything I could read that would show cases where signed variables are preferable when negative values are impossible?

Comment: @qdii: the main argument is that using unsigned types for arithmetic can be error-prone and mixing unsigned and signed types in expressions is particularly so. Basically, just because your value is non-negative doesn't mean you won't use it in an expression with other signed values, and surprise yourself with an implicit conversion. Arguably the root problem is that C++ is weakly typed as far as numeric types are concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t), which has to be a signed integer. It has to be signed because it can be used as the difference between two iterators, and that can of course be negative.

Comment: +1. Damn I should have created an answer and not a comment... but yeah, that's right.

Comment: So the next question is, why do they use `std::ptrdiff_t` for std::count, and it is answered in another post. so, thanks.

Comment: @qdii `std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type` is the same as the iterators `difference_type` which defaults to `ptrdiff_t` (as seen e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). Why the distance is specified as `ptrdiff_t` is _probably_ because iterators can be used much like pointers, but the (C++11) specification doesn't actually give a reason as to why, it just specifies it has to be that type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I'd have thought that the reason `difference_type` defaults to `ptrdiff_t` is that pointer subtraction results in a `ptrdiff_t`. So `iterator_traits<T*>::difference_type` has to be `ptrdiff_t`, and it makes sense for the default for iterators to be whatever it is for pointers. I may be missing some reason that you want a stronger explanation than that, though.