# Why is size_type in std::array size_t and in std::vector usually size_t?

Tags: c++, stdvector, size-t, stdarray

The documentation says, that `size_type` of `std::vector` is /usually/ `size_t`, which is reasonable, since an implementation can choose to use different.

But why is `size_type = size_t` in `std::array`. Especially here, as `std::array` is used on small `µC` a lot, it would be better to let the implemenatation have some freedom.

Is this a doc-defect?

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? Different C++ vendors have different STL implementations with different documentation and extensions. I'm not aware of any single _official_ STL documentation (which would be irrelevant anyway, as vendor/STL-specific documentation would always take precedence).

Comment: @Dai It is defined by the C++ Standard that [`std::array<T,N>::size_type` is `size_t`](http://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-4).

Comment: @DanielLangr Ah yes, the authoritative source - but I wouldn't describe the ISO spec as "documentation" because specs generally aren't useful as a reference for users, and are intended for vendors.

Comment: I **speculate** it has something to do with the fact the template-parameter `N` is also typed as `size_t` and because `std::array` simply wraps a native C++ array (granted, the spec does not require this, by my reading), if `size_type` could be something other than `size_t` it would complicate things and imply that the indexer operator did some processing to the index argument before using it as an offset for the native array. But otherwise, no idea :) Whereas in `vector<T>` those constraints don't apply.

Comment: Comparing the specs for `vector` next to `array`, I see that `vector` is not required to be a _contiguous container_ when `T` is `bool`, and the definition of `size_type` needs to differ when used with a non-contiguous container (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505083/why-does-the-c-standard-algorithm-count-return-a-difference-type-instead-of ), whereas `array` is always contiguous, hence the hardcoded `size_t`.

Comment: That is understandable. But I wonder, why this is not for std::array. An implementation coud decide to make size() of type uint8_t if the size of an instantiation of std::array is less than 256. This whould be especially good for µC implementation.

Comment: Despite the fact that non-type parameter T is of type size_t, the size_type could be a smaller unsigned type. array could you a meta-function to determine the smallest type for the size. I use this procedure in my own implementation, but I wonder why the wording of the standard is that way.

Comment: @Dai The specification is the *only* relevant documentation. Anything that disagrees with it is wrong by definition, including anything the vendor wrote.

Comment: @user207421 If I'm using a C++ compiler that violates the ISO C++ spec, then I know it's wrong - but it's my compiler, so I still have to to abide by what it does - even if it's "wrong". And if its wrongness allows me to ship faster and get dat sweet customer base, then being wrong feels so right :)

Answer (score 2):

It's defined to be that way because `size_t` is defined to be sufficient for all arrays. If you want a smaller type for smaller arrays, you can always narrow when appropriate based on `constexpr` values.

```
template <typename Array>
struct small_array_size
{
    using type = size_t
};

template <typename T, size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<N < 256>>
struct small_array_size<std::array<T, N>>
{
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template <typename T, size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<N < 65536>>
struct small_array_size<std::array<T, N>>
{
    using type = uint16_t;
};

template <typename Array>
using small_array_size_t = typename small_array_size<Array>::type;
```

Comment: Thats all ok, but I wonder why the standard say (cppreference) says, that size_type in arrays must be an alias for size_t?

Comment: @wimalopaan because that's what the committee decided on. It's more surprising that `container::size_type` exists *at all*, and isn't just `size_t` everywhere

Comment: Yes, an because container::size_type exists, it should not be fixed to size_t. std::vector the wording is "usually size_t". And the same wording I would suggest for std::array. So I suppose it's a wording flaw and not intional.