# Exact width integers in C++/Qt: Is typedef int qint32 really correct?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

The Qt documentation says:

> **typedef qint8**
>
> Typedef for signed char. This type is guaranteed to be 8-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.
>
> **typedef qint16**
>
> Typedef for signed short. This type is guaranteed to be 16-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.
>
> **typedef qint32**
>
> Typedef for signed int. This type is guaranteed to be 32-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.
>
> **typedef qint64**
>
> Typedef for long long int (__int64 on Windows). This type is guaranteed to be 64-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.

The types are defined in  `qglobal.h` as follows:

```
/*
   Size-dependent types (architechture-dependent byte order)
   Make sure to update QMetaType when changing these typedefs
*/
typedef signed char qint8;         /* 8 bit signed */
typedef unsigned char quint8;      /* 8 bit unsigned */
typedef short qint16;              /* 16 bit signed */
typedef unsigned short quint16;    /* 16 bit unsigned */
typedef int qint32;                /* 32 bit signed */
typedef unsigned int quint32;      /* 32 bit unsigned */
//....
```

But I'm wondering how (for example) `qint32` can always be 32 bits long when there is no guarantee that `int` is 32 bits long. <del>As far as I know, on 64-bit architectures `int`s are (or at least can be) 64 bits long.</del> [EDIT: I was wrong. See comments below.]

How can they guarantee the sizes? Why don't they use `stdint` (and __intN on windows platforms)?

Comment: This doesn't have to work on all platforms, just on all platforms supported by Qt.

Comment: Yes, but Qt also supports 64 bit plattforms.

Comment: @leemes - `int` is still 32 bits on those platforms. But `long` might differ.

Comment: @BoPersson Ok thanks, I didn't know that. Excuse me the slightly off-topic question: On 64 bit plattforms, is `int` as fast as a 64 bit `long`?

Comment: @leemes - On the platforms Qt supports (x86-64?) an `int` operation is a byte shorter and uses less data than a 64-bit value. That might make it faster. On the other hand, a 64-bit op handles twice the amount of data, *should you need that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can they guarantee the sizes?

They target specific platforms that they know that the above definitions work. Qt doesn't care for other platforms and [other platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about) don't care about Qt. So, it won't always work. But where it won't work neither will Qt.

> Why don't they use stdint (and __intN on windows platforms)?

Sometimes it's simpler to maintain the typedefs in `<stdint.h>` for your own project rather than conditionally including the standard header on platforms that have it *and* still maintaining a fallback for platforms that don't (e.g. VS2005).

Answer (score 1):

Qt supports many platforms, but what matters is the platform's 64-bit data model (or probably more correctly, the compiler plus platform's data model).

Most common 64-bit platforms use 32-bit integers because they implement some form of the LP64 data model.  The ILP64-based data models (ILP64, SILP64, etc) define ints as 64-bits.  But I don't believe Qt supports any of these [platforms](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/supported-platforms.html).

Check out the [ILP64 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILP64#Specific_C-language_data_models) and this [support page for PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/) that has some good technical information.