# How to use BinaryReader class to read a custom file (C++) using C#?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, binaryreader

Okay, so, for a personal project I've been given the task to code a tool to make use of a custom file that was serialized from C++ using C#.

I thought of using `BinaryReader` class and effectively that was the right path but as I suspected I couldn't get any useful info without the structs used to serialize the file, so I asked for them. The problem is that the info I was sent is 2 struct names containing all `qint32` fields (yes they use Qt Library).

To be honest I'm completely lost with this, also I'd like to know if `qint32` is Qt's `int32` representation or if it's effectively different from it.

Regards.

Comment: Tagging your question with `C++` and `Qt` might get you more results from people who know that framework!

Comment: Okay, I'll do it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692051/exact-width-integers-in-c-qt-is-typedef-int-qint32-really-correct) a `qint32` is 32 bits in length.

That means you can use [`BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the numbers assuming they are little endian.

The definition for `qint32` from qglobal.h is as follows:

```
typedef int qint32;                /* 32 bit signed */
```

The C++ standard does not specify the endianness of numbers, instead the architecture the program is compiled on does.  x86 and x64 processors are little endian.  Note that it is possible to change the endianness of a number (e.g. by using the [`htonl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).  To get a definitive answer, you should ask whoever generated the file.

Comment: What about the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)? Is it same?..

Comment: @L.B I've added some more info.  If it's from an x86 or x64 machine it's probably little endian.