# How to portably (de)serialize qint32?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

The documentation of Qt states that `qint32` is a typedef for `signed int` and is guaranteed to be 32-bit on all platforms supported by Qt. [[docs]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint32-typedef)

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) states that `signed int` must not be smaller than `short` and must be at least 16 bit in size. So there is no guarantee of the size in the typedef alone. Qt gets around that [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692051/exact-width-integers-in-c-qt-is-typedef-int-qint32-really-correct) though.

So for (de)serialization with Qt this is good because the size will always be that. However this does not say anything about binary representation of those numbers I assume. And that matters when (de)serializing portably. For example doing this:

```
QFile file("somefile");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
qint32 i = 10;
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
file.flush();
file.close();
```

will write `qint32` of value 10 to a file in a binary form. When I send that file over a network to another app written in Qt doing this:

```
QFile file("somefile");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint32 i = 0;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
file.close();
```

I will indeed get a number back but is it guaranteed to always be 10? I do not think so as the binary representation of 10 on that machine might differ. But it is possible I understand it wrong and this is a non-issue (for Qt supported platforms at least).

Hence my question: How to portably (de)serialize primitive types in Qt? Or is the size guarantee enough?

Comment: Note also that Qt does not even compile unless `CHAR_BIT == 8` and `sizeof(int) == 4`. This is explicitely tested: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp.html#106

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) for (de)serializing.  It writes to/reads from anything that inherits from QIODevice and has explicit input and output operators for qint32.

Comment: Thanks, the docs are even explicit : "A data stream is a binary stream of encoded information which is 100% independent of the host computer's operating system, CPU or byte order. For example, a data stream that is written by a PC under Windows can be read by a Sun SPARC running Solaris." which I have missed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that for all platforms supported by Qt the following holds `assert(CHAR_BIT == 8)`.

Given that assumption, the only thing to worry about is byte endianness. Unfortunately, your cast does not take endianness into consideration. It writes the integer in native endianness, and reads assuming the data is native.

De facto standard solution is to always convert to/from the *network endianness*, which is big endian. You'll find that Qt provides functions to do exactly that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtendian.html

Edit: although, you might want to check out G.M.'s answer rather than implement serialization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited with binary representation. Serialize them to a string (Qt has JSON support for example)