# Can bit-fields be used as a «poor man's» fast integer type?

Tags: c++

I've just noticed an interesting property of gcc with regard to bit-fields. If I create a `struct` like the following:

```
template <int N>
struct C
{
    unsigned long long data : N;
};
```

Then on amd64:

1. with *-m64*, for N ∊ <1, 64>, `sizeof(C) == 8`;
2. with *-m32*, for N ∊ <1, 32>, `sizeof(C) == 4` and for N ∊ <33, 64>, `sizeof(C) == 8`.

(with `sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8`).

That seems to *mostly* resemble the C99/C++11 `uint_fastXX_t` except for the fact that on my system `sizeof(uint_fast8_t) == 1`. But for example, I can't reproduce anything similar with `__int128` (which always results in `sizeof(C) == 16`).

Does it seem like a good idea to you to use the fore-mentioned `struct` as a «poor man's» replacement for `uint_fastXX_t` *in C++98*?

Comment: It is the poor man's *bit* type.  Maps poorly to most cpu architectures, they take an extra cpu cyle or two.

Comment: @HansPassant: some proof would be approved.

Comment: You get the proof by measuring it. Don't ever not measure.  You might as well program in Java if you don't measure.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'd say that assembly is a good enough proof for me. And the two solutions are giving *identical* assembly for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No -- a bit-field will frequently be considerably *slower* than a bare, unadorned `int`, because if you do something (e.g., addition or multiplication) that might overflow the designated size, the compiler will (typically) insert a bitwise `and` instruction to ensure that the result fits in the specified size. E.g., if you multiply two 10-bit numbers and put the result in a 10-bit field, the multiplication may produce up to a 20-bit number, so the compiler will normally produce the 20-bit result, the use a bitwise `and` to get the 10 least significant bits for the result.

Comment: Well, I was considering using it as a… bit-field! In other words, `&`, `|`, `~` and `bool`-ing the whole value.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. On  most systems we care about, `uint_fast32_t`, `uint_least32_t`, and `uint32_t` will be the same type.

It is only on [exotic hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972551/597607) the fast/least types might be 36 bits, for example, instead of 32.

Comment: So, you don't care about 64-bit systems or am I misunderstanding your intentions?

Comment: It's just an example. Not all systems are 32- or 64-bit. On the (slightly exotic) system I linked to, `unsigned long long` would be 72 bits, but `sizeof(unsigned long long)` still 8 (with `CHAR_BIT` == 9).

Comment: But say, if I need 8 bits of them for a bit-field, wouldn't an `unsigned long long:8` (or `unsigned long:8`) bit-field be more likely optimal than a random type like `char`?