# Why does an unsigned char return the same value as a signed char in c++?

Tags: c++

I was under the impression that both would be set to different values but all three of these things are outputting the exact same character. Is there some kind of implicit conversion going on or what?

```
unsigned char unsc1 = 128;
std::cout << "Unsigned Char 1 = " << unsc1 << std::endl;


signed char sc1 = 128;
std::cout << "Signed Char 1 = " << sc1 << std::endl;



char c1 = 128;
std::cout << "Char 1 = " << c1 << std::endl;
```

The same thing happens when both are set to 254, it was my understanding that a signed variable type shouldn't be able to hold as much data as one that was unsigned.

Comment: They aren't strings, a char value of 128 is equal to a certain character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both signed and unsigned characters would be interpreted as `char` when you send it to `cout` unchanged. If you would like to see different results, cast these values to `int` before printing:

```
unsigned char unsc1 = 128;
std::cout << "Unsigned Char 1 = " << (int)unsc1 << std::endl;


signed char sc1 = 128;
std::cout << "Signed Char 1 = " << (int)sc1 << std::endl;
```

Now on probably all extant platforms the `signed char` would print -128, while unsigned one would print `128` (according to the standard, chapter 4.7, section 3, it is implementation-defined).

([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/jFIHjY)).

Comment: The second is UB when `CHAR_BIT` is 8 IIRC. I'm pretty sure initialization "overflow" counts, right?

Comment: @chris I need to check the standard, but I think you're right.

Comment: I see the different results now, and the -128 is expected. Did they change that at some point in C++? I was under the impression that when you set a Char to a value that it would return the appropriate character associated with that value.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I think I was wrong and it's implemnetation-defined per §4.7 [conv.integral]/3.

Comment: @chris: That's right - conversion from unsigned to signed is implementation defined, but signed *overflow* (i.e. the result of an arithmetic operation) is undefined.

Comment: @chris You-re right - I just found the 4.7.3 part myself ("If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.")

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: instead of me editing more, let me just mention that [some Texas Instruments digital signal processors have 16-bit `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about). I forgot to mention the byte size in my edit. Also, that the unsigned result is guaranteed (regardless of platform).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Cool, thanks for that link. It's a lot nicer when you actually have a real example.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, 128 is not a printable ASCII code. So none of your three statements will get a character. At least in my environment, gcc version 4.1.2, libc6,x86-64

Comment: Be aware that there is a wide variety of possibilities for the character with code 128. For example, in Windows 1252, it is €. In UTF-8, it is a control character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is correct:

```
signed char sc1 = 128;  // overflow.
```

You seem to try something resulting kind of 'undefined behavior'.

Comment: If you haven't seen it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481322/why-does-an-unsigned-char-return-the-same-value-as-a-signed-char-in-c#comment37893875_24481359