# Relation between numeric representation of memory address and alignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-alignment

Example:

```
std::ptrdiff_t dist(void* a, void* b)
{
    return static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(b) - static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(a);
}

Align8Type align8; // alignof(Align8Type) == 8
std::uintptr_t(&align8) & 3; // [1]
dist(nullptr, &align8) & 3; // [2]
Align8Type* p = reinterpret_cast<Align8Type*>(static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(nullptr) + dist(nullptr, &align8));
assert(&align8 == p); // [3]
```

**Assuming `std::uint8_t` is supported**, are the results of [1] & [2] guaranteed to be 0 and is [3] guaranteed to be true in c++ standard?
If not, what about in practice?

Comment: You seem to assume a byte addressed machine, which is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @BoPersson Any reference?

Comment: The fact that such machines exist. See for example [Exotic architectures the standard committees care about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about)

Comment: The standard doesn't even guarantee the existence of `uint8_t`

Comment: `uint8_t` must exist on an 8-bit-addressed machine. Clearly this question only pertains to such machines

Comment: Doesn't the C++ memory model define a byte as `char` independently of the underlying machine's representation, @BoPersson? Also, a byte is not necessarily an octet, if that is what you wanted to express.

Comment: @Ulrich - Yes, the language standard defines a byte as the space a `char` occupies. It doesn't require that each char resides at a distinct memory address. For example, the old Univac I refer to in my link stored four 9-bit characters in each 36-bit word. As a memory address was much shorter than 36 bits, a char-pointer could store info about "part-word access" to the individual characters. And everything else was 36-bit aligned by default. On the other hand, it wouldn't have the type `uint8_t` defined so the code above wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard makes no guarantees about the representation of a pointer [Note 1]. It is not necessarily the case that the values of a pointer map directly into consecutive integers, nor that pointers to types with different alignments have the same representation. So any of the following are *possible*:

1. Segment/offset representation where the segment number occupies the low-order bits of the pointer representation.
2. Pre-aligned representation, where the low-order 0s of the address of an object with known alignment are deleted from the representation.
3. Flagged representation, where the low-order bit(s) of pointers to certain object types are used to identify an aspect of the type, and do not participate in address resolution. (An example of this would be a hardware-assisted garbage-collection architecture in which the low order bits of pointers to types large enough to be pointers are repurposed as GC flags.)
4. Subword addressing representations, where the underlying hardware is word-addressed (and a word is considerably longer than 8 bits), but a hardware or software solution is available for byte addressing where a byte pointer consists of a pair of word address / subword offset. In this case, a byte pointer will be larger than a word pointer, which is allowed by the standard.

I'm sure there are other possibilities.

An alignment must be a power of 2, but there is no guarantee that more than one alignment exist. It is entirely possible for all types to have alignment 1. So it may well be on a given architecture that it is impossible to meaningfully define `Align8Type`.

Given all the above, my interpretation:

1. `std::uintptr_t(&align8) & 3 == 0`

   False. Even if `Align8Type` is definable, there is no guarantee that the conversion of `Align8Type*` to `std::uintptr_t` is to a number divisible by 8. On a 32-bit word addressed machine, for example, the underlying hardware address mod 8 could be 0, 2, 4 or 6.
2. `dist(nullptr, &align8) & 3 == 0`

   False. The subtraction of `nullptr` from a pointer to an object is Undefined Behaviour. (§5.7/5: "Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.")
3. `reinterpret_cast<Align8Type*>(static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(nullptr) + dist(nullptr, &align8)) == &align8`

   False. First, as per 2., the invocation of `dist` is Undefined Behaviour. Second, adding that value to a null pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

   Round-trip conversion of `T1*` to `T2*` and back to `T1*` is guaranteed provided that the alignment requirements of `T2` are less strict than `T1` (§5.2.10/7). In this case, `T1` is `Align8Type` and `T2` is `uint8_t`, and the alignment restriction presumably holds, so if it were not for the undefined behaviour of the arithmetic, this would work. That is, you could cast `&align8` to `uint8_t*` and then cast it back to `Align8Type`. You could even add the integer `0` to the intermediate `uint8_t*` pointer, but no other integer.

---

Do these identities work *in practice*? They probably work on C++ implementations on 8-bit byte-addressed 2's complement machines, which are pretty common (a lot more common than the theoretical beasts mentioned above, which are, statistically speaking, as common as unicorns). But technically, they render your code non-portable. I have no idea what aggressive optimizations might do to the UB mentioned in points 2 and 3, so I wouldn't suggest risking it in production code.

---

#### Notes:

1. §3.9.2/3:

   > The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined.

   §5.2.10/4:

   > A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is
   > implementation-defined. [ Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. —end note ]

   I reproduced the note, because it is interesting: in order to understand the representation of an address as an integer, you must understand the underlying machine's addressing structure (which, by implication, might not be as simple as a contiguous sequence of integers).

Comment: Most of us seem to assume the numeric representation of a pointer directly maps to the consecutive address, even in Boost.Align!

Comment: @Jamboree: And it does, on all modern architectures that I know of.  But the standard doesn't require it to. (Many low-level libraries also assume that you can freely subtract pointers which do not point into the same array, but the standard is quite clear that you cannot. It's valid for a library to do that if it has some preprocessing protection which limits its applicability to architectures in which the assumption is known to be correct.)

Answer (score 0):

In the C++ standard,

> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store
>   any member of the implementation’s basic character set.
>
> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A
>   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the
>   Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence
>   of bits, the number of which is implementation defined.
>
> Every byte has a unique address.

A `uint_8` is not necessarily a byte. And a byte is not necessarily 8 bits

**Are the results of [1] & [2] guaranteed to be 0?**

Supposing Align8Type to have an address 8 byte aligned:

[1] Yes: by definition of the previous supposition.

[2] Yes, Even if the byte size could be bigger than uint_8,supposing Align8Type has an address 8 byte aligned, the address will be multiple of 8. (uint_8 is smaller or equal to a byte)

**Is [3] guaranteed to be true in c++ standard?**

No: `dist` return the `uint_8` distance between both pointers, not the address distance.

EDITED:

edited to answer the redefined question.

Comment: I wasn't very clear in the question, I added some prerequisite and used `std::uint8_t` to avoid the `char` problem. Note that in [3] it's `std::uint8_t* + dist` and then cast back to `Align8Type*`.

Comment: 1 char = 1 byte, this is defined by the standard

Comment: @M.M Do you have any reference to that assertion?

Comment: @Adrian Maire Yes, it's defined in the standard.

Comment: Ok, I found it: 5.3.3. I do not know why is not specified in the char specification but in the sizeof operator.

Comment: All I can find is that since C++14 `char` must implicitly convertible to and from a type with 256 values and that `unsigned char` can be used to inspect objects at the raw-memory level.

Comment: the standard `byte` does not necessarily need to be 8-bits. Although since `sizeof()` and all other pointer operations are defined based on that standard `byte` it doesn't really matter for this question.

Comment: @PeterT: the question was slightly different in the first version. That the why of this  char vs bytes.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I remember the standard doesn't define the mapping between a pointer and its numeric representation. Any source to back up your answer?

Comment: @Jamboree: "The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes." I understand contiguous as address contiguous, not as hardware contiguous (which do not mean anything).