# Is the size of every C data type guaranteed to be an integer multiple of bytes?

Tags: c, c11, c89

I know that sizeof(char) will always be 1, and that this is in units of bytes, and that a byte can be any number of bits (I believe any number of bits greater than or equal to 8, but not positive on that).

I also commonly see references that mention how C data type sizes can be specified in terms of the relationship between their sizes, such as "sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)".

My question is basically: What would "sizeof(int)" evaluate to on a system where a byte is 8 bits and an int is 39 bits (or some other value which is not evenly divisible by CHAR_BIT).

My guess is that sizeof() returns the minimum number of bytes required to store the type, so it would therefore round up to the next byte. So in my example with a 39 bit int, the result of sizeof(int) would be 5.

Is this correct?

Also, is there an easy way to determine the number of bits a particular type can hold that is 100% portable and does not require the inclusion of any headers? This is more for a learning experience than an actual application. I would just use stdint types in practice. I was thinking maybe something along the lines of declaring the variable and initializing it to ~0, then loop and left shift it until it's zero.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is in the first two lines of [Wikipedia article about `sizeof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)

Comment: `int` can't be 39 bits in that situation. Any type you can apply `sizeof` to will consist of a whole number of bytes. (Bit-fields can have fractional sizes but they're not really a type, and using `sizeof` on them is an error.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wikipedia isn't authoritative.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper And SO is?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I never said it was. I'm just saying you can't link to Wikipedia and say matter-of-fact "the answer is in". The only authoritative source is the C standard.

Comment: I don't think anyone would build such a machine. I have once upon a time worked on [a 36-bit machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about/6972551#6972551), but it had `CHAR_BIT == 9`, not 8.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The Wikipedia article states "...measured in the number of char size storage units required for the type". I guess the distinction is with how you interpret the word "required". Does "required" imply that every type is an integer multiple of bytes in size? I interpreted that statement as "sizeof(type) will return the minimum number of bytes required to store the type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.2.6 Representations of types**
> **6.2.6.1 General**
>
> 1. The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.
>
>    **Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes**,
>    the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or
>    implementation-defined.
>
>    Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type `unsigned char` shall be
>    represented using a pure binary notation.<sup>49)</sup>
>
>    **Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of `n × CHAR_BIT`
>    bits, where `n` is the size of an object of that type, in bytes.** The value may be copied into
>    an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is
>    called the object representation of the value. Values stored in bit-fields consist of `m` bits,
>    where `m` is the size specified for the bit-field. The object representation is the set of `m`
>    bits the bit-field comprises in the addressable storage unit holding it. Two values (other
>    than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal, but values that compare
>    equal may have different object representations.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>49) A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values
> represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral
> powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position. (Adapted from the *American National
> Dictionary for Information Processing Systems*.) A byte contains `CHAR_BIT` bits, and the values of
> type `unsigned char` range from `0` to `2^CHAR_BIT − 1`.</sup>

> My question is basically: What would "sizeof(int)" evaluate to on a system where a byte is 8 bits and an int is 39 bits (or some other value which is not evenly divisible by CHAR_BIT).

The implementation would have to map `CHAR_BIT`-sized storage units onto odd-sized words such that the above requirements hold, probably with a significant performance penalty.  A 39-bit word can hold up to four 8- or 9-bit storage units, so `sizeof (int)` would *probably* evaluate to 4.

Alternately, the implementor can simply decide it's not worth the hassle and set `CHAR_BIT` to 39; *everything*, including individual characters, takes up one or more full words, leaving up to 31 bits unused depending on the type.

There have been real-world examples of this sort of thing in the past. One of the old DEC PDPs (I want to say the PDP-8, maybe PDP-11?) used 36-bit words and 7-bit ASCII for character values; 5 characters could be stored in a single word, with one bit unused.  All other types took up a full word.  If the implementation set `CHAR_BIT` to 9, you could cleanly map `CHAR_BIT`-sized storage units onto 36-bit words, but again, that may incur a significant performance penalty if the *hardware* expects 5 characters per word.

Comment: Thanks for citing the standard. I just have a question about your response:

> [...A 39-bit word can hold up to four 8- or 9-bit storage units, so sizeof (int) would probably evaluate to 4.]

If CHAR_BIT were 8, then it seems like this would violate #4 under 6.2.6.1 because it states that "the value may be copied into an object of type unsigned char [n] (e.g., by memcpy)". (With "n" being the result of sizeof(type)". 

In this case, if "n" were 4, then this would not work because you have a total of 39 bits to store, but your array consists of 4*8 bits.

Comment: It was the PDP-6 and PDP-10. But the 7-bit character was just a convention; the machines were word-addressed but had opcodes permitting the use of any bitrange within a word. Normal addresses were 18 bits, so two of them fit into a word; bit-range references required an entire word. A word could contain six alphanumerics, allowing six-character variable names to fit in a word; more aggressive compression (not using bitranges) allowed the use of seven-character case insensitive identifiers. It's not easy to see how a hypothetical C compiler might allow for such flexibility.

Comment: @JakeMoroni: Admitting up front that such a thing probably doesn't exist, imagine an architecture and instruction set that allows you to mask and access arbitrary regions of a 39-bit word, such that you could map a contiguous sequence of 8-bit "bytes" where every fifth "byte" or so would span a word boundary. Logical "byte" addresses would not line up with physical word addresses, meaning the performance would *suck*, but that's how I envision such an implementation.  In which case multi-byte type sizes are entirely arbitrary.

Comment: @JohnBode Actually, the OP asked about 39-bit `int`s, not about `int`s within 39-bit words. (As a result, while your answer is correct, the part of 39-bit words is confusing. It might help if you added a note about 39-bit `int`s before that.)

Answer (score 6):

What people often fail to understand is that, in C, there's a clear distinction between `sizeof` and "width".

"width" is more about binary representation, range, overflow/wrap-around behavior. You say a unsigned integer type is 16-bit wide then you mean it wraps around at 65535.

However `sizeof` only cares about storage. Hence `sizeof(T[n])==sizeof(T)*n` is maintained by allowing `sizeof` to include paddings.

For this reason it makes little sense trying to find connections between `sizeof` a type and the arithmetic behavior of a type: a type can have a certain range but can take whatever storage space it wants.

To answer your question ("what if a 39-bit int on a 8-bit-char machine?") I'd like to use TI C6400+ as an example, because it has a 40-bit `long` and 8-bit char, very close.

TI C6400+ is a byte addressable machine so it must define 8-bit byte as `char`.

It also has a 40-bit-integer type because the ALU can operate on 40-bit integers, and they defined it as `long`.

You would think `sizeof(long)` should be 5, right?

Well, it could, but this CPU also does not supported unaligned-load very well, so for performance reasons this `long` type is by default aligned to 8-byte boundaries instead of 5-byte, then each `long` has 3 bytes of paddings (in both memory and register level because it takes a pair of GPRs in the CPU, too), then naturally `sizeof(long)` becomes 8.

Interestingly the C6400+ C implementation also provides `long long` and `sizeof(long long)` is also 8. But that's a truly 64-bit wide type and has full 64-bit range instead of 40-bit.

**UPDATE**

So back to the "39-bit" case.

Since 6.2.8.1 require the alignment of all complete types be an integer multiple of "bytes", then a 39-bit integer must be padded to at least 40 bits or larger if `CHAR_BIT` is 8, so `sizeof` such a type must be an integer greater or equal to 5.

Comment: I realize the distinction, which is why I wondered if sizeof() would round up. 

The only guarantee that I rely on is that "char" is of the smallest type and that it contains CHAR_BIT bits. The _storage_ size of all other types is a multiple of bytes, and therefore contains n * CHAR_BIT bits (as per 6.2.6.1). However, as your example proves, this doesn’t necessarily reflect the arithmetic capabilities of the type. My question was really about whether “n” had to be an integer or not, which is why I chose a 39 bit int in my example rather than a number which was evenly divisible by CHAR_BIT.

Comment: @JakeMoroni Then that is more about alignment than size. 6.2.8.1 says alignment is "a integer number of bytes". In C "byte" is `char` then yes, it must be divisible, or padded up to a multiple of CHAR_BIT.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the size of every C data type guaranteed to be a multiple of bytes?

Yes. Even if number of bits required to represent the data type is smaller than `CHAR_BIT` for example `struct foo { unsigned int bar : 1};` or `int16_t` on a system with `CHAR_BIT` = 32.

```
sizeof(char) = 1 (guaranteed)
CHAR_BIT >= 8 ( = 8 on posix compliant system)
sizeof(anything else) = k * sizeof(char) = k where k is a whole number
```

From **6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an **integer**.
>   [...]

To add to your confusion, on a machine with `CHAR_BIT = 32`, `sizeof(int16_t)` will be 1, and so will be the `sizeof(int32_t)` and you may actually end up allocating more bytes of memory than required (I am not sure though) if you use `malloc(sizeof(int16_t) * n)` instead of `malloc(sizeof(int16_t[n])`.

Comment: When `CHAR_BIT = 32`, `sizeof(int16_t)` can not be 1, because `intN_t` can not have padding bits. It won't be provided by a 32-bit-char implementation at all. And `sizeof(int16_t) * n` and `sizeof(int16_t[n])` are exactly the same.

Comment: You shouldn't use a bitfield as an example, because it contradicts the rest of your answer. A bitfield takes up exactly the amount of bits you specify. Otherwise, it takes `n * CHAR_BIT` bits, where `n` is the number of bytes.

Comment: int16_t can not exist if CHAR_BIT == 32

Comment: @sleeptightpupper padding bits are present after bitfields to ensure correct alignation.