# c++ building custom serialization

Tags: c++

i am trying to build custom serialization that can work on any computer, 
i tried it and am successful and tried even in 3 other computer and it is running correctly,

i read a line about a library specifying "serialize & de serialize in the same computer".

What is it could possibly go wrong if i serialize and de serialize in different computers. is there any architecture or operating system or endianess difference.

and i cannot use standard libraries either like boost etc...

Comment: What is your question exactly? I find it hard to answer this question, because I am not sure what you are asking. Yes you should be aware of endianness differences and word-size differences, but you seem to know that already? :)

Comment: I am asking will there be any endianess problem or architecture problem or os problem if i serialize in one computer and de serialize in other computer

Comment: If the two computers are of different endianness, yes you can write non-portable serialization-code in C++ that will not run correctly on both machines. However you can also write portable code that does not fail on different architectures. It depends on how you write your code, and from your question (which shows no code), I cannot tell :) May I suggest you post your code so we can judge it, or explain in words which techniques you are using.

Comment: You might want to take a look over here: [Exotic architectures the standards committees case about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about)