# C++11 data types confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, types, char, int

I am trying to write a solid summary for C++ datatypes, but I have some confusion about the new datatypes.

As I understood from my readings about C++ data types, `char16_t` and `char_32_t` are fundamental data types and part of the core language since C++11.

It is mentioned that they are **distinct** data types.

Q1: What exactly does "distinct" mean here?

Q2: Why `intxx_t` type family like `int32_t` was chosen not to be a fundamental datatype? And how can they be beneficial when choosing them instead of `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the second part of the question:

The fixed size integer types are inherited from C, where they are `typedef`s. It was decided to keep them as `typedef`s to be compatible. Note that the C language doesn't have overloaded functions, so the need for "distinct" types is lower there.

One reason for using `int32_t` is that you need one or more of its required properties:

> Signed integer type with width of *exactly* 32 bits
>   with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values.

If you use an `int` it might, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about), be 36 bits and use 1's complement.

However, if you don't have very *specific* requirements, using a normal `int` will work fine. One advantage is that an `int` will be available on all systems, while the 36-bit machine (or a 24 bit embedded processor) might not have any `int32_t` at all.

Answer (score 4):

The `charXX_t` types were introduced in [N2249](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2249.html). They are created as a distinct type from `uintXX_t` to allow overloading:

> Define `char16_t` to be a distinct new type, that has the same size and representation as `uint_least16_t`. Likewise, define `char32_t` to be a distinct new type, that has the same size and representation as `uint_least32_t`.
>
> [N1040 defined `char16_t` and `char32_t` as typedefs to `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, **which make overloading on these characters impossible.**]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your Q1:

Distinct type means `std::is_same<char16_t,uint_least16_t>::value` is equal to `false`.

So overloaded functions are possible.

(There is no difference in size, signedness, and alignment, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Other way to express "distinct types" is that you can create two overloaded functions for each type. For instance:

```
typedef int Int;
void f(int) { impl_1; }
void f(Int) { impl_2; }
```

If you try to compile a code snippet containing both functions, the compiler will complain about a ODR violation: you are trying to redefine the same function twice, since their arguments are the same. That's because `typedef`s doesn't create types, just aliases.

However, when types are truly distinct, both versions will be seen as two different overloads by the compiler.