# Convert unsigned char array into uint8_t array?

Tags: c, unsigned-char

I need convert unsigned char array into unit8_t array maybe someone has an idea how to do it?

I tried to look for information on the Internet, but unfortunately I did not succeed.

:)

Comment: There's nothing to convert. **Iff** `uint8_t` exists, it is the same as `unsigned char`. Or the other way around: If `unsigned char` has more than 8 bits, there's no `uint8_t` available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, have you tried `uint8_t* myuint8array = (uint8_t*)myuchararray;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
unsigned char arr[size];
```

and you want

```
uint8_t arr[size];
```

uint8_t is simply defined as

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

:-)

Comment: Or not defined at all, in case `char` has more than 8 bits.

Comment: And when would a character possibly have more than 8 bits?

Comment: @Robert - It could for example be 9 bits [on a 36-bit computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972551/597607).

Comment: character != `char`. And then, the answer is "*when it has more than 8 bits*". Yes, such platforms exist and they can't provide `uint8_t` for obvious reasons.

Comment: This was complete news to me, i have never heard of this before. Thanks, will read this straight away. :-)

Comment: @RobertK because such platforms exist, C only mandates a *minimum* of 8 bits for `char`. But `uint8_t` must have **exactly** 8 bits, so this type will be missing on a platform having larger `char`s.

Comment: @RobertK that is why `#define CHAR_BIT 8` (for example) appears in `limits.h`

Comment: @WeatherVane Interesting. Learn something new every day :-)

Comment: @RobertK funny you should say that ... so do I!