# Do we have atomic uint32 type in C?

Tags: c, atomic, c11

`sig_atomic_t` is a typedef of `int`. But I am curious do we have an atomic type which is matched to `uint32_t` ?

Comment: It might be that your system has no 32-bit types *at all*. Like if it is a [36-bit computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972551/597607),

Comment: Note that `sig_atomic_t` is different from the types in `<stdatomic.h>`. It does not provide inter-thread synchronization and the only guarantee is that it's an indivisible type. Often used in combination with `volatile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 defines following typedefs to atomic types in `<stdatomic.h>`:

```
atomic_bool
atomic_char
atomic_schar
atomic_uchar
atomic_short
atomic_ushort
atomic_int
atomic_uint
atomic_long
atomic_ulong
atomic_llong
atomic_ullong
atomic_char16_t
atomic_char32_t
atomic_wchar_t
atomic_int_least8_t
atomic_uint_least8_t
atomic_int_least16_t
atomic_uint_least16_t
atomic_int_least32_t
atomic_uint_least32_t
atomic_int_least64_t
atomic_uint_least64_t
atomic_int_fast8_t
atomic_uint_fast8_t
atomic_int_fast16_t
atomic_uint_fast16_t
atomic_int_fast32_t
atomic_uint_fast32_t
atomic_int_fast64_t
atomic_uint_fast64_t
atomic_intptr_t
atomic_uintptr_t
atomic_size_t
atomic_ptrdiff_t
atomic_intmax_t
atomic_uintmax_t
```

There is no `atomic_uint32_t`, so your options are:

- You can use `_Atomic(uint32_t)` directly.
- You can use one of existing alternative types (`atomic_uint_least32_t`, `atomic_uint_fast32_t` or even `atomic_char32_t`) if this fits your purpose (probably it doesn't).
- You can assume `atomic_uint` is 32-bit and use it as a replacement. This should be actually one of the most portable ways as most OS (*BSDs, Linux, Windows) assume `int` is a 32-bit type.

Comment: but I didn't find stdatomic.h packaged in my gcc. Which gcc version has it?

Comment: @damingzi I don't know when it first appeared, but GCC 7.3 has it.

Comment: "You can assume atomic_uint is 32-bit and use it as a replacement" -- no, you can't. That's the whole point of `uint32_t`.

Comment: @JasonS Yes you can. In many cases `uint32_t` is `unsigned` and this is mandated by your platform.

Comment: I work on embedded processors. We cannot make such assumptions.

Comment: As a practical matter, you may be able to anyway as long as you assert that it is the case and are grateful when the assertion fails because that loud obvious immediate failure gave you a chance to respond before having to debug anything.

Comment: Blindly assuming `int` is 32-bit is plain wrong. Don't do that ever. It has always been 16-bits *minimum*. If you need 32-bits use `long` or one of the fixed size types.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau You don't have to do it blindly. POSIX has always guaranteed `int` to be at least 32-bit. In the end, contrary to popular misconception, C standard _does not define your environment_ - your OS has the final say in that. Which is why some implementations use 8-bit `int` (GCC on AVR with `-mint8`), even though `int` is "16-bits minimum".

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not define atomic types with exact sizes since a platform may not be able to handle exact sizes atomically. Even though a system has the type `uint32_t`, it may not be able to handle operations with that type atomically but maybe only with the type `uint64_t`, that's why there is only `uint_least32_t`, which guarantees you a type that for sure has 32 bits available but that could be mapped to `uint64_t` as well if a platform requires that for atomic operations.

The standard does allow you to use `_Atomic(uint32_t)` but even in that case it does not guarantee that this results in a type that has exactly 32 bits but instead the compiler is free to map that to the type that's nearest to the requested type and does allow atomic operations, which, again, could be `uint64_t` on some platform.

Note that the C standard itself never guarantees the existence of exact types, like `uint32_t`. Those types are optional to begin with. Only the POSIX standard requires those exact types to exist, yet the POSIX standard does not require them to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer is great (I hope you accept his, not this one), but it's worth mentioning that some compilers (I'm looking at you, MSVC) don't support C11 atomics.

If you're not concerned with such compilers, use C11 atomics.

If, OTOH, you need a bit portability, you may want to take a look at the [atomic module](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/atomic) in [Portable Snippets](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/) (disclaimer: it's one of my projects, so take this suggestion with a grain of salt). There is no *unsigned* 32-bit atomic, but there are 32- and 64-bit *signed* atomic types which work well with a *lot* of compilers, including old (pre-C11) GCC, clang, and ICC, as well as suncc, ARM, and a few others.